# How to draw straight line in a tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I need to draw line from my central node to every other node.
I know how to draw from point to point:

```
\draw[darkblue2, thick](virt-manager)--(libVIRT);
```

I know also that I can specify where the draw goes out/in with:

```
\draw[darkblue2, thick][out=270](virt-manager)to[in=110];
```

But the draw are rounded and that's not what I want.
Here is the code, in black this is what I need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                calc, chains,
                %decorations.pathmorphing,
                fit,
                %petri,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.misc}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{31,22,70}
\definecolor{darkblue2}{RGB}{21,126,251}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={fill=#1,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=5cm,rounded corners,
                   draw=white,very thick,font=\sffamily\color{white}},
    mynode/.default=gray!20]
        \node[mynode=darkblue!50] (libVIRT)at (b) {libVIRT};
        \node[above  = of libVIRT,mynode=darkblue!20, minimum width = 2cm] (OpenStack) {OpenStack};
        \node[left = of OpenStack,mynode=darkblue!20, minimum width = 2cm] (virsh) {virsh};
        \node[left = of virsh,mynode=darkblue!20, minimum width = 2cm] (virt-manager) {virt-manager};
        \node[right =of OpenStack,mynode=darkblue!20, minimum width = 2cm] (oVirt) {oVirt};
        \node[right =of oVirt,mynode=darkblue!20, minimum width = 2cm] (else) {autres};

        \node[below = of libVIRT,mynode=darkblue!80, minimum width = 2cm] (kvm) {kvm};
        \node[left =of kvm,mynode=darkblue!80, minimum width = 2cm] (ESX) {ESX};
        \node[left =of ESX,mynode=darkblue!80, minimum width = 2cm] (LXC) {LXC};
        \node[right =of kvm,mynode=darkblue!80, minimum width = 2cm] (Xen) {Xen};
        \node[right =of Xen,mynode=darkblue!80, minimum width = 2cm] (autres) {autres};

        \draw[darkblue2, thick][out=270](virt-manager)to[in=110](libVIRT);


   \end{tikzpicture}    
   \caption{blabla}
\end{figure}      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364461/how-to-obtain-rectangular-lines-between-nodes-with-tikz

Comment: Thx for the help